# C# Get the local function from class that inherits from abstract class

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class, instantiation

I try to get access to a function in a class that inherited from another (abstract) class. But I only have an access to property from upper class, and do not have access to the function from the class I instantieted.

```
public abstract class A
{
    public abstract string getString { get; }
}

public class B: A
{
    public override string getString 
    { 
        get => "String";
    }

    public string getOtherString()
    {
        return "oterString";
    }
}

class C
{
    private A localClass;

    C()
    {
        localClass = new B();

        string test1 = localClass.getString; // Works well 
        string test2 = localClass.getOtherString(); // Does not work
    }
}
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: You've declared `localClass` as a type `A`. declare it as a `B` instead and it will work.

Comment: In my case I have to do it, because my construction more difficult than it is related.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an instance of `A`(base class) you cannot access members from `B`(child). You either have to declare `private B localClass` or cast it to `B`:

```
string test2 = ((B)localClass).getOtherString();
```

This fails at runtime if `localClass` is not of type `B`.

Comment: And to me, having to do that would be an extreme code smell along with a red flag. If I _need to_ call the `B`-specific interface, how can the reference be an `A`? => I did something wrong!

Comment: @Fildor: Yes. But sometimes it might be necessary to check if it's a specific type, he could use the `as`-operator: `B b = localClass as B; string test2 = b?.getOtherString()`

Comment: "Exceptions confirm the rule" :D I am just saying - I probably would question my design choices. Of course, there could be an edge case where it makes sense to do "it" by type checking.